# XUnit - Stop all tests in collection if one fails

Tags: c#, xunit

I am writing integration tests for my API application.

I have used WebApplicationFactory to create an instance of the API in memory and now I am writing multiple tests (using XUnit) that follow in sequence to test end to end.

I was able to sort the ordering of the tests using the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/order-unit-tests?pivots=xunit

Which works quite nicely.

The issue I am having is can I stop the tests if one fails? as the previous test will be required to pass in order to complete the next...

example...

```
//GET call to get a date from the DB

    Test1()

//POST call to change the date and update in DB

    Test2()

//New GET call to get new date, and compare new to original to confirm success

    Test3()
```

If Test2() fails I want to stop all other tests (within that collection - XUnit)

I came across this exact question from an old post but it doesnt seem like it was possible back then?

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/856

Has anyone any idea on this? or can point me in the right direction, ThankYou for any replies

Comment: That feels like one test, not 3. And more like an integration test than a unit test. Unit tests should not depend on any external shared state. You should be able to run any single unit test in isolation.

Comment: I have broken the test down into 3 to speficy exactly what is happening and will be easier to understand for the developer as the naming convention explains exactly what it does, and will pin point any problems. Also XUnit was used to avail of their ordering (please see link proviided)  [Fact, TestPriority(1)], unless you have another suggestion? to calify these are integration not unit

Comment: Have you looked at setting [StopOnFail](https://xunit.net/docs/runsettings)?

Comment: Hi NPras no I havent seen this before thank you for the tip I will check it out!